# What happens when terraform template is rendered

Tags: terraform

I came across a terraform example code regarding template_file in the below link

https://blog.james-carr.org/using-templates-in-terraform-17bb8f4a0aac

policies/s3_bucket_readonly.json.tpl

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}",
    "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/${key_prefix}"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow"
}
]
}
```

Terraform script

```
data "template_file" "cloud-trail-logs-s3-readonly" {
template = "${file("policies/s3_bucket_readonly.json.tpl")}"
vars {
    bucket_name = "${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail-logs.bucket}"
    key_prefix = "AWSLogs/*" 
}
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "cloudtrail-logs" {
bucket = "cloudtrail-logs"
acl = "private"
lifecycle_rule {
enabled = true
noncurrent_version_expiration {
  days = 30
}
}
}
resource "aws_iam_policy" "cloudtrail-logs-readonly" {
name = "prod-cloudtrail-logs-s3-readonly"
path = "/production/"
description = "Readonly access to cloudtrail-logs bucket"
policy = "${data.template_file.cloud-trail-logs-s3-readonly.rendered}"
}
```

Can someone explains what the ${data.template_file.cloud-trail-logs-s3-readonly.rendered} actually does ?? Does it simply apply the template variable values to the policies/s3_bucket_readonly.json.tpl and add the same as policy ?? If yes, then what does ".rendered" mean or stand for ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, even if your wording is inaccurate. It's the result of the template policies/s3_bucket_readonly.json.tpl **after** variables are applied.

Have a look at the docs (attributes reference) https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html#attributes-reference

> rendered - The final rendered template.

The value of the policy will be the content of the template after terraform renders it.

After the HCL is interpreted (the terraform language is called HCL - Hashicorp Configuration Language), "**${bucket_name}**" will be equivalent to "**${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail-logs.bucket}**" as passed in the template resource in the vars block, and "**${key_prefix}**" to **AWSLogs/***

I think "**${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail-logs.bucket}**" will refer to the string "**cloudtrail-logs**" (value of the bucket attribute in the aws_s3_bucket resource)

So the policy value should be:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::cloudtrail-logs",
    "arn:aws:s3:::cloudtrail-logs/AWSLogs/*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow"
}
]
}
```

Comment: so ".rendered" is what causes the variables in template to be replaced by the values ?

Comment: I would say not "what causes" but it is the result. Running terraform apply is what causes the variables in template to be replaced by the values.

Comment: To clarify, the terraform code id not interpreted all at once. The template is rendered first, and only after that blocks that depends on it are intepreted as well. You can have a look at https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/graph.html.

But let's say you don't use .rendered anywhere in your code, the template is still rendered but the result is never used even if it is available

Comment: I think that clarifies it...Thanks